# shift values from hash keys

Tags: ruby

I have this value

`{:cat=>["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"], :dog=>["dog1", "dog2", "dog3"]}`

And I'm looking to retrieve/shift values from each key:

ie:

get the following:

```
[{:cat => "cat1", :dog => "dog1"}, {:cat => "cat2", :dog => "dog2"} ... etc]
```

I'm really not sure the best way to approach this, any suggestions?

Edit:

So far I have:

```
a[a.keys.first].dup.map{|c| a.map{|index, vals| vals.shift}}   
# => [["cat1", "dog1"], ["cat2", "dog2"], ["cat3", "dog3"]]
```

Though not quite what I want due to lack of keys.

Comment: First make it work, then make it pretty. Do you have any ideas (not necessarily the best) how to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want to get, shifted values or remaining ones?

Comment: I want all the values, but incrementally shifted into an array of hashes for all the attributes, if that makes sense.

Comment: "if that makes sense" - no, not really, but check out my answer. Maybe it's what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
a = {:cat=>["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"], :dog=>["dog1", "dog2", "dog3"]}

a1 = a.each_with_object({}) do |(k, vals), memo|
  shifted = vals.shift
  memo[k] = shifted
end

a # => {:cat=>["cat2", "cat3"], :dog=>["dog2", "dog3"]}
a1 # => {:cat=>"cat1", :dog=>"dog1"}
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thanks, I think I was over simplifying it trying to do with within just a map/inject..

Comment: Why do you define `shifted`?

Comment: @samuil: I thought this would make code more readable. I'd probably do the same in my real world code.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't modify original hash:

```
h = {:cat=>["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"], :dog=>["dog1", "dog2", "dog3"]}

h.values.first.zip(h.values.last).map do |value_pair| 
  Hash[ h.keys.zip(value_pair) ]
end

# => [{:cat=>"cat1", :dog=>"dog1"}, {:cat=>"cat2", :dog=>"dog2"}, {:cat=>"cat3", :dog=>"dog3"}]

h
# => {:cat=>["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"], :dog=>["dog1", "dog2", "dog3"]}
```

Array#zip: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip

Comment: My apologies, I usually run the code, but this time I didn't. Also it looks like your answer more closely follows specs from the question. Have a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {:cat=>["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"], :dog=>["dog1", "dog2", "dog3"]}

ks = h.keys
h.values.transpose.map{|vs| Hash[[ks, vs].transpose]}
# => [
#   {:cat => "cat1", :dog => "dog1"},
#   {:cat => "cat2", :dog => "dog2"},
#   {:cat => "cat3", :dog => "dog3"}
# ]
```

Or, strongly pushing a one-liner, slightly sacrificing the speed:

```
h.values.transpose.map{|vs| Hash[[h.keys, vs].transpose]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cats_and_dogs = {:cat=>["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"], :dog=>["dog1", "dog2", "dog3"]}

cats_with_dogs = []
i = 0
cats_and_dogs[:cat].each do |e|
    cats_with_dogs << {cat: cats_and_dogs[:cat][i], dog: cats_and_dogs[:dog][i]}
    i+=1
end

cats_with_dogs # [{:cat=>"cat1", :dog=>"dog1"}, {:cat=>"cat2", :dog=>"dog2"}, {:cat=>"cat3", :dog=>"dog3"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although not quite what I was looking to define the keys within the loop. Solved below.